# django webserver on travis for e2e testing

Tags: django, angularjs, travis-ci

A quick question for some Django / Travis pros.

I would like to run some e2e tests on travis for my django/angular app, and connect to sauceLabs through a sauceConnect tunnel.

```
//travis.yml
    addons:
      sauce_connect: true
      postgresql: "9.3"

branches:
  only:
  - master
  - integration_env

language: python

python:
- '2.7.9'

cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  - node_modules
  - bower_components

install:
- npm install
- pip install -r requirements.txt
- pip install coverage -U --force-reinstall
- pip install coveralls -U --force-reinstall
- node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update


before_script:
- psql -c 'create database travisci;' -U postgres
- pg_restore --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -d travisci demoDB.dump
- python manage.py runserver &

script:
# - grunt karma:sauceTravis

- grunt protractor:sauceLabs
- coverage run --source='.' manage.py test

after_success:
- grunt coveralls:run
- coveralls --merge=coverage/lcov/coveralls.json
```

I try to run a django webserver on my travis CI environment. I do this in a before_script after I create my database.

When I try to ping localhost:8000, however, I get a "bad gateway 301" response. Says something about dirty ssl?

If anyone has any advice about how to go about debugging this, I would be grateful.

Thanks